# Compute the probability of the sum of n random numbers from a given set to be greater than X?

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-probability

I want to figure out a way/formula by which I can compute the probability of the sum of n random numbers to be greater than X. All the random numbers fall in the range of [−1000,−1.01]∪{0}∪[1.01,1000] and step size is 0.01

Each random number is chosen independently.

Use Case: I am working on the development project of a gaming engine. For each round a player is awarded a random score in the range of [−1000,−1.01]∪{0}∪[1.01,1000]. In the beginning, player can make a bet that after n rounds of the play the total sum of his score will be X. I just want to get the probability of the accuracy of his bet.

Current Progress - I was able to somehow get the results using brute force approach (n rolling dice problem), however the brute force method is taking lots of computation power. I want an efficient formulae/solution (in terms of computation)

I don't know if Convolutions is the right approach for it.

Thanks for the help, in advance!

Comment: Independence is not enough to say much.  Are the values chosen uniformly at random?

Comment: If the prob. of choosing a value is uniformly and the number of rounds is sufficently large enough you can apply the *central limit theorem*.

Comment: Despite the funky shape of your range near $0$, I would probably start by approximating that you're drawing uniformly from $[-1000, 1000]$.  Then the next question is what is $n$?  For large $n$ the central limit theorem works well, as @callculus already mentioned.  For small $n$ this can be solved precisely (given the uniform approximation) in terms of low-degree polynomials.  (I believe degree $n$?)  Please tell us your $n$ of interest?